# Programms to calibrate depth_image from kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to find programs to get the values for the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters but RGBDemo has old ubuntu-package  dependencies (have (14.04)) I cannot solve and Matlab toolbox from Herrera is quite complicated. Any suggestions? What I want to end up with is a proper yaml-file or at least with the parameters to fill in like shown in the [camer_calibration_parsers wiki.](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers?distro=jade#YAML)

 **EDIT** I used D. Herrera and [Burrus](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration)'s data for depth monocular calibration and I ended up with:

```
    image_width: 640    //Region of Interest
    image_height: 480
    camera_name: depth_A70774V01752221A     //@change Seriennummer anpassen
    camera_matrix:  // = Matrix K beinhaltet Intrinsik
      rows: 3
      cols: 3
      data: [594.25, 0, 339.79, 0, 592.48, 242.50, 0, 0, 1]
    distortion_model: plumb_bob     //Lochkamera-Modell
    distortion_coefficients:    // Entzerrungs-Vektor k
      rows: 1
      cols: 5
      data: [-0.26167, 0.99319, -0.00102, 0.00536, -1.29664]
    rectification_matrix:   // Rotations-Matrix  !not R
      rows: 3
      cols: 3
      data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    projection_matrix:      //  Matrix [mod(K)|t]
      rows: 3
      cols: 4
      data: [594.25, 0, 339.79, 0, 592.48, 242.50, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226084/programms-to-calibrate-depth_image-from-kinect/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-10**:
maybe an update to the wiki for kinect is a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni_launch package has several [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials) on calibrating the Kinect. These include finding the [intrinsic calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) parameters for the RGB and IR sensors, and an [extrinsic calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/ExtrinsicCalibration) for better registration between depth and IR cameras.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1